# Compile Angular app error

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I'm having problem getting the latest ASP.NET Boilerplate (core + angular 3.0.0 stable) to work.

First I'm having this warning when running `yarn`.
[image: Warning from yarn]

After that I continued running `npm start` and got this warning as well as error for the webpack (webpack: failed to compile).
[image: Warning from npm start]
The webpack error
[image: Webpack error]
[image: Webpack compile failed]

I've used the earlier version which runs fine with `yarn` and `npm start`. Anything I did wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you run `npm install` 
to install all dependencies package of the app. Then run compile command again:

```
ng serve
```

**Update**

The issue is `web-animations-js` package missed. Just run `npm install web-animations-js  --save`, then compile app again.

Comment: I've tried `npm install` but still get the same error.

Comment: Which folder do you run npm install? The correct path is ../angular, check node_modules exists inside the folder after you run the command.

Comment: Yup I ran the `npm install` in the `/angular` directory and verified that the `node_modules` folder is there. But still to no avail. Tried also deleting the `node_modules` folder and re-run npm install but still have this problem.

Comment: Ah I missed something. The web-animations-js package dose not exist. Run "npm install web-animations-js --save", then compile app again.

Comment: Your last comment works. Put it as an answer so that I can mark it.